# Разлочка модема

Tags: модемы

Подскажите, определился модем Huawei 171,как:/dev/sr1 в операционной системе Ubuntu. Изменил настройку последовательного порта в minicom, вошел в консоль minicomа, а он не хочет вводить АТ команду. Курсор не мигает и буквы не вводятся. Может я что не так делаю, помогите разобраться.

#### UPDATE

Как сделать, что бы модем определился как usb устройство. Программа usb-modeswitch установлена. Отсоединил модем, вытащил симку, вставил модем в usb и выдает окно, диск не может быть смонтирован, далее много текста на английском, где и был прописан /dev/sr1. Может в терминале нужно что то прописать? У меня версия Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: У вас модем определился как cd. А нужно, чтобы определился, как usb устройство.